# Getting a blank page when using Selenium web driver and Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

Firefox is opening a blank website when using Selenium web driver (geckodriver) for this handy tool [here](https://github.com/donwayo/ebayKleinanzeigen)

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: What do you get if you run a `which geckodriver` in a command prompt terminal?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver